# Open a link from a popup window in a new tab in the parent window

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, popup, window, parent

Is it possible to have a link in a popup window open in a new *tab* in the parent window?

Here's the flow: I have a page with a link on it (call it Page A). Clicking the link on Page A opens a popup window (Page B). Clicking a link on Page B opens another page (Page C) in the parent window, but it *replaces* Page A.

What I want to do is have the link on Page B (the popup) open Page C in a new *tab* in the parent window, so that Page A remains open.

Comment: besides its technial issue, is it really a user friendly state?

Comment: You don't really have access to the browser tabs and windows. With the targets you only have access to the __parent and __self. So, not really helping there. Every browsers handles tabs and windows differently and don't forget that some browsers don't even have tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
 parent.window.open("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow");
```

otherwise please post what you already have and we'll pick it up from there....

Comment: Nice! In Firefox, it opens Page C in a new tab in the parent window; in Safari and IE, it opens Page C in a new window entirely. I guess it depends on how each particular browser handles it. Either way is fine though as the goal is to not have the browser navigate away from Page A. Thanks!